# MongoDB query using $near not working when nested

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coordinates, 2dsphere

I have several documents in my Articles collection. Every document has a location value and some extra data. The location value looks like this:

```
"loc" : {
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : [ 
        4, 
        54
    ]
}
```

I can build an index by executing the following command:

```
db.articles.ensureIndex({loc:"2dsphere"});
```

And I can query documents based on their location and a $maxDistance with the following query:

```
db.articles.find({ loc : { $near : {$geometry : {type : "Point" , coordinates : [4, 54] }, $maxDistance : 1000 } } });
```

This works perfectly!

**However** when I change the location of my "loc" object in my document, my query always returns zero results. My document should look like this (This is a minimized version):

```
{
    "articledata" {
        "content": {
            "contact": {
                "loc" : {
                    "type" : "Point",
                    "coordinates" : [
                        4.1,
                        54
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I rebuild my index query:

```
db.articles.ensureIndex({"articledata.content.contact.loc":"2dsphere"});
```

and execute my query again after changing my 'loc' location in the document:

```
db.articles.find({ "articledata.content.contact.loc" : { $near : {$geometry : {type : "Point" , coordinates : [4, 54] }, $maxDistance : 10000 } } });
```

There are no results.

It's probably some stupid mistake but I really can't find the problem...

Is there anyone who can help me out?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it work if you add a colon after "articledata"?

Comment: Following your steps, everything works fine for me. Your example documents aren't well-formed and I had to add in {'s and a : to get them to work, so perhaps we didn't use exactly the same documents? Check carefully and try again; if things still don't work, edit the question to include the exact, well-formed documents that you are using.

Comment: I don't know why but now it somehow works. Like @skieter suggested, I moved the location of "loc" to "articledata" and rebuilt my index. This worked. I then moved it to my ideal location and it kept on working (after an index of course). I don't understand it but I'm happy it's fixed. Thanks for the replies!